# Is there a way to search for transactions by custom field?

Tags: braintree

I store specific custom field for each transaction. I'd like to conduct a search by this field. I wouldn't like to retrieve too many transactions (can filter by payment method id, but still) and iterate through them on application side. So, I read a documentation, didn't find an ability to search by custom field (only by predefined). I didn't try it out, but probably it's possibly to do so by following the same pattern like

```
var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
    search.myCustomField().is("custom_field_value");
    // or search.customFields.myCustomField().is("custom_field_value");
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I work as a developer for Braintree. Searching on custom fields is not supported at this time. You can see all of the searchable transaction attributes [listed here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/request/transaction/search).

If you would like to discuss alternatives, I recommend emailing our support team at support@braintreepayments.com to see if there is another method to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: just hijacking your comment to ask you again if you have this feature in your backlog? Really need this feature to sort using our custom fields :(

Comment: Yes, this feature should be added!

Comment: Is there any plan for this feature to be added?

Comment: It's 2022 and it's still not supported. I don't understand the reasoning, the same feature is available on the dashboard.